# How to define JSON custom scalar type in graphql which can be nullable?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/3532#issuecomment-1125126566

serialize() can not return null, so I'm getting GRAPHQL error {"errors":[{"message":"Expected `JsonType.serialize(\"null\")` to return non-nullable value, returned: null" error where JsonType is my customized scalar.

I know graphql-scalars package includes a JSON scalar type, but I'm using my custom one where serialize() can parse from a Buffer or string. It used to work but in graphql 16 I can not return null in serialize() after [this](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/pull/3231) change.

I'm wondering what's the recommended way to handle it in this case, if I use a wrapper all schema would need to change due to the nesting.

Comment: The graphql-scalars package includes a JSON scalar type. I recommend you checkout its [source](https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-scalars/tree/master/src/scalars/json)

Comment: @MichelFloyd  I'm using my custom one where serialize() can parse from a Buffer or string.

Comment: Why not just return `null` or 'undefined` directly without serialization when the value is `null` to avoid the serialization error?

Comment: @MichelFloyd wondering how I can do that?

Comment: Show your code otherwise it's hard to say